# $g(x) \in[a, b]$

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods

Let $g(x)$ be a contraction mapping in $[a, b]$ with $L<1$ such that
$$
\left|g\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)-\frac{a+b}{2}\right| \leq(1-L) \frac{b-a}{2}
$$
Prove that $g(x) \in[a, b]$ ,  $ \forall x \in[a, b]$.
I need to prove this but I don't know what to do, could anyone help me?

Comment: Try out some concrete values of $a$ and $b$ to convince yourself this is true before you try to write a proof

Comment: Also, notice $\frac{a+b}{2}$ is the midpoint between $a$ and $b$.  That should help you

Comment: @D_S I'm sorry, but I don't know how this helps me

Comment: Do you know what a contraction mapping is?

Comment: @D_S Yes, a mapping that satisfies $|gx)-g(y)| \leq L|x-y|, \forall x, y \in [a,b]$, where $ L<1$

Comment: Is it clear to you that $g(\frac{a+b}{2})$ lies in the interval $[a,b]$?  Try showing that if $x$ is near the midpoint $\frac{a+b}{2}$, then it too lies in $[a,b]$.

Comment: @D_S Why does $g\left( \frac{a+b}{2} \right) \in [a,b]$

Comment: That this is a total mystery to you is why I suggested first trying the problem with concrete values of $a$ and $b$, e.g. think about what the problem is saying when $a = 0$ and $b=6$.  Right now, many finer details are too abstract for you to grasp and they would become clearer if you first work with numbers instead of letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $m=\frac{a+b}2$ and $r=b-m=m-a=\frac{b-a}2$. Then the stated equation is
$$
|g(m)-m|\le (1-L)r
$$
Now apply triangle inequality and Lipschitz condition to
$$
|g(x)-m|=|g(x)-g(m)+g(m)-m|
$$
using that $|x-m|\le r$.

Comment: I don't think this question should be answered with a complete proof.  The student will learn nothing

Answer (score 1):

Here is what is going on when $a = 4$ and $b = 10$.

Since $g$ is a contraction mapping, there is a number $0 < L < 1$ such that $|g(x) - g(y)| \leq L|x-y|$ for all $x, y \in [4,10]$.

Your hypothesis is that $|g(7) - 7| \leq 3(1-L)$.

You are trying to show that if $4 \leq x \leq 10$, then also $4 \leq g(x) \leq 10$.  What does this mean?  It means that $g(x)$ is no more than three units away from $7$.  In other words, you are trying to show that $|g(x) - 7| \leq 3$.

How to show this?  Use the triangle inequality:

$$|g(x) - 7| = |(g(x) - g(7) + (g(7)-7)| \leq |g(x) - g(7)| + |g(7) - 7|.$$

Now, each of the numbers $|g(x) - g(7)|$ and $|g(7) - 7|$ is bounded by certain numbers.  Add the bounds.